# Unwanted repetition in StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
  Dim sw As StreamWriter
    For x As Integer = 0 To 20
        Dim validchars As String = "cfeabd0123456789"

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim rand As New Random()
        For i As Integer = 1 To 32
            Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
            Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
            sb.Append(randomChar)
        Next i

        Dim randomString = sb.ToString()
        sw = File.AppendText("C:\file.txt")
        sw.WriteLine(randomString)
        sw.Close()
    Next
```

What it does is creating 20 random sentences with the "Validchars" declared in the 3rd line and then it writes the output into a text file with appending feature . I want to write one output per line for example :

```
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
7ca00313c590f990fa797c73ec1d3305
303a7364c220f3d02c5df8b5b39e00ae
```

But the problem I get is that it repeats the lines many times , here's an example output (I have deleted some lines to make it shorter) :

```
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
4926022cabea67acc9c95035ff6ec492
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
c45a315faa856e1c681e7ddd5d2c1276
```

As you can see instead of putting one output per line it repeats the output many times and then it does the same for the next output ... Please help

Comment: `New Random` with no other arguments or settings always restarts from the same place.

Comment: Not exactly, new Random() will Initialize a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value. The loop is very fast, then some lines get the same millisecond, and the same sandom seed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: As explained in the answer you got, the repetition didn't have anything to do with the `StreamWriter`. In any case, you should use it "more properly". Initialising it as `sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\file.txt", True)` is more than enough to append files (you don't need the `sw = File.AppendText("C:\file.txt")` bit for anything). Also you might be interested in putting it inside a `Using` statement (which would avoid the last `sw.Close()` and will dispose it properly).

Comment: @Tony good answer. But the OP was using `StreamWriter` and thinking that it was the reason why he got the unwanted behaviour; in your solution you have replaced it; what might be misunderstood as "better don't use the StreamWriter" (what is not the case, at all).

Comment: Thank you, I undestood what you said, and put the StreamWriter back. I also let commented with other code that uses File.AppendAllText

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the Random from the Loop

```
Sub GenerateRandomFileContent()
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim sw As StreamWriter
    For x As Integer = 0 To 20
        Dim validchars As String = "cfeabd0123456789"

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        For i As Integer = 1 To 32
            Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
            Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
            sb.Append(randomChar)
        Next i

        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)  ' Remove this line if not needed

        ' Appends the Text to file
        Dim randomString = sb.ToString()
        sw = File.AppendText("C:\file.txt")
        sw.WriteLine(randomString)
        sw.Close()

        ' To Append this Text you could use just these lines below
        'Dim randomString = sb.ToString()
        'File.AppendAllText("C:\file.txt", randomString)
    Next
End Sub
```